# In 18.04 change language of date?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

So just updated to 18.04 and one thing really bugs me, the date given by Gnome is written in my native language while I prefer the date to be given in English. So instead of: "za 19:24" in Dutch I'd rather have: "sat 19:24" in English. I found the setting to change formats but I'd like to preserve the other options of the Dutch format (i.e how numbers are shown). Is it possible to change the Dutch format to basically have the date/day displayed in English or make my own custom format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the difference between how the numbers are displayed in Dutch vs English?

Comment: 1,000.00 is what we use ;)  PEREZje PM me if this is not what you asked for ;)

Comment: Should also be aware that on US first day of the week is Sunday, as opposed to Monday on many European countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware that there are two locale settings. One that is used before the user login, and another after the user login. Furthermore, **simply editing the /etc/default/locale is likely not to work** because it will be overwritten by the "Regional Formats" set on the GUI.

Using `locale` it will inform you the locale preferences currently being used. Using `localectl status` will let you know the preferences used before user login, like on the login screen.

If you want to edit the locale for your user, the first thing you want to know is which locales are available. For that, type `locale -a`. After checking that your locale of choice is already installed (you will likely want to check if`en_US.utf8` is available).

Now, the file you want to edit is `~/.pam_environment`. This is the one that will determine the regional settings used after being logged in. You can open it with your editor of choice (no need for sudo). In your case you want to edit simply the time settings, so go over to that line and replace it with `LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8` and leave the others with your country settings.

If you also want that change to take effect when in the login screen you should use `sudo update-locale LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8`.

Note that changes only happen after a fresh login or system restart.

Relevant: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Answer (score 8):

The locale for numbers is called:

```
LC_NUMERIC
How you format your numbers. For example, 
in many countries a period (.) is used as a 
decimal separator, while others use a comma (,).
```

and for date/time is:

```
LC_TIME
How your time and date are formatted. 
Use for example "en_DK.UTF-8" to get a 24-hour-clock 
in some programs.
```

Change LC_TIME to US and you will see american style date, but since LC_NUMERIC is not changed numbers stay as is.

---

Example:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ date
za  4 aug 2018 21:20:11 CEST
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ 

rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ 
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ date
Sat Aug  4 21:16:53 CEST 2018
```

If you like it, change:

```
/etc/default/locale
```

to make it permanent.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Gnome does not support this - at least not through its standard settings dialog.  The 'classical' approach however, changing your locale settings so that `libc` returns the proper internationalised strings, should work.

The gentle way of doing it, but I'm not sure if Gnome will pick this up, is by setting the environment variable `LC_TIME` to `en_GB.UTF-8` or `en_US.UTF-8` in your `~/.profile`.

If that does not work, and you don't mind making this setting the system default (dates in your log files, for instance, will also be formatted in English), set this value in `/etc/default/locale`.  It should already have an `LC_TIME` entry.  Make sure no `LC_ALL` setting overrides it.

If that does not work either, then a radical way of accomplishing your goal is by modifying your locale definition (which I assume is `nl_NL` in your case).  To do this, edit the file `/usr/share/i18n/nl_NL` and modify the strings in the `LC_TIME` section.  When done, run `sudo locale-gen`.  Note: you'll need to redo this after every update to the `locales` package.

In all cases, reboot to pick up the changes.

A cleaner but quite elaborate alternative would be to create your own user-defined locale, say `nl_NL@withenglishdates`.  See `/etc/locale.gen`, and `man localedef` if you want to go that way.

Comment: Creating the .profile file and adding LC_TIME = en_GB.UTF-8 only changed the date after logging in. The log-in screen did not change. @Podesta his answer worked for both. Still thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I gave a livecd boot and it was normal.
 Take the test there.
 If you stay the way you want, I suggest you do a clean installation. If you upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, there may have been some remnants of Unity and you are getting in the way.

Comment: What? I did a clean install so no remnants from 16.04. What I mean is is that I live in the Netherlands so the date is displayed in Dutch (za 20:23) which is short for zaterdag. But I'd prefer it if it was displayed in English (sa 20:23). But I want to do it without changing the way numbers are displayed because I prefer the Dutch way in this. If I change the format language it also changes other things, but I'd like only for the language of the date to be changed.